# Python Queues put data

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing queues. The Queue is created in Main Process and a child process gets from it. However, all the data from the main process is not passed to the Queue until an SIGINT is sent.

#### Main Process

```
log_q = Queue()
```

#### Sub Process

```
while True:
     msg = log_q.get()
     # log the msg
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: How do you know the data isn't passed?

Comment: @phd coz im printing it as soon as get is gets a value. Other process also pass messages to the same Queue and that is processed. All the messages from Main Process are printed only when a SIGINT / SIGTERM is sent. while messages from other processes are printed correctly